# apex_data_parser file > 50MB

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a page to upload a file using apex_data_parser when the user click the button.

- The SQL bellow using apex_data_parser to upload a file with 550K rows and 52 MB  take about 180 min to finish.
- The same file, same page, but I delete some rows and keep 500K rows and 48 MB, take about 8 min to finish.
- I had tested with the same file 750K rows and 40 MB (I delete the column with some description to stay bellow 50 MB) took 15 min
- Somebody have any ideia why the time is so different with the file above 50 MB?
- Reading the API the limit is 2GB and 4GB to the file

The SQL I took from the sample upload in app App Gallery

```
FOR r_temp in (SELECT line_number, col001, col002, col003, col004, col005, col006, col007, col008      
                       from apex_application_temp_files f, 
                            table( apex_data_parser.parse(
                                   p_content                     => f.blob_content,
                                   p_file_type => 2, 
                                   p_skip_rows => 1,                                       
                                   p_file_name                   => f.filename ) ) p                          
                      where f.name = p_name)
LOOP 
...
```

## It's a .csv file

```
Column Position Column Name Data Type   Format Mask 
1   LINE    NUMBER  -
2   ACCOUNT NUMBER  -
3   DATETIME_CALL   DATE    YYYY"-"MM"-"DD" "HH24":"MI":"SS
4   TYPE_CALL   VARCHAR2(255)   -
5   CALL    NUMBER  -
6   DURATION    NUMBER  -
7   UNIT    VARCHAR2(50)    -
8   PRICE   NUMBER  -
```

## What I did next?

To simplifie the problem I changed the sql statement to a simple count(*).

I have create a demo account at oracle cloud and started a Autonomous Transaction Processing using the same file, same appplication to test. The results: File greater than 50MB 6 hours to execute a SQL count statement (see attachament bellow). File with 48MB 3 minutes to execute the same SQL count statement. Maybe a apex.parser limit?

This chart below is interesting, the User I/O goes up a lot, only with > 50 MB in my tests. 
I took the 50 MB file that has processed OK in 3 minutes and copy some rows to increase until 70 MB (so the file is not corrupt)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please see the answer for this question in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60616754/oracle-apex-apex-data-parser-execution-time-explodes-for-big-files

Comment: I believe the answer can be found in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60616754/oracle-apex-apex-data-parser-execution-time-explodes-for-big-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the answer can be found in this question: [Oracle APEX apex_data_parser execution time explodes for big files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60616754/oracle-apex-apex-data-parser-execution-time-explodes-for-big-files)

Comment: Hi Jakobmhc and welcome to Stack Overflow. When you have a question and cannot comment it is better to post a new question, including a link to the old question in your post. Currently you have posted your question as an "answer" which means it will be removed by the mods.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a function of the file size, it's more a function of the shape and width of the data.

180 minutes is a super long time.  If you're able to reproduce this, can you examine the active database session and determine the active SQL statement and any associated wait event?

Also - what file format is this, and what database version are you using?

Comment: I have create a demo account at oracle cloud and started a Autonomous Transaction Processing using the same file, same appplication to test. The results: File greater than 50MB (70MB in my tests) 6 hours to execute a SQL count statement (see attachament above in the question with the monitoring from Autonomous DataBase). File with 48MB 3 minutes toto execute the same SQL count statement. Maybe a apex.parser limit?