# Oracle APEX apex_data_parser execution time explodes for big files

Tags: oracle-apex

(Sorry don't have enough rep-point to comment on the similar asked question)

When the apex_data_parser processes file of more than 50MB, execution time explodes.
As in the question asked here: [apex_data_parser file > 50MB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59393013/apex-data-parser-file-50mb/60614488), I must agree with oCoXa, there must be a bug in the parser.

I find exactly the same issue on ATP + APEX 19.2.0.00.18.
I also see the spike in IO and CPU when parsing files >~50mb, no spike at all when below 50mb.

I have loaded two files to a table (A41_temp_files), one being 54mb, the other one 47mb. (same rows until 47mb)
In both cases I'm just parsing 3000 lines of the respective 171.000 and 199.000 lines in the files.

I run the parser in SQL Developer, it take 1,9sec for 47mb and 88,6sec for 54mb.

```
select * 
from A41_temp_files  f,
    table(  
            apex_data_parser.parse(
                p_content                     => f.BLOB_CONTENT,
                p_max_rows                    => 3000,
                P_DETECT_DATA_TYPES => 'N',
                p_file_name                   => f.FILENAME 
            ) 
        ) p
where 1=1
and f.filename = 'CHUCK_47mb.txt' --3000 lines    1,9sec
--and f.filename = 'CHUCK_54mb.txt' --3000 lines 88,6sec
order by col001
;
```

[I/O and CPU usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccYui.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the APEX_DATA_PARSER package has indeed a 50MB "threshold".

For BLOBs smaller than 50MB, APEX creates a new, cached(!), temporary LOB, copies the data over and does all parsing on that temporary LOB. So all LOB operations happen in memory.

If the BLOB is larger than 50MB, no temporary LOB is created and the LOB operations of APEX_DATA_PARSER are performed on the LOB Locator which has been passed in. In your case, it's the LOB locator for your column A41_TEMP_FILES.BLOB_CONTENT. Thus all the LOB operations happen in disk, which makes it slower.

APEX is built to run on shared instances with many workspaces and parallel users as well - so this threshold is to protect the (shared) SGA and database memory.

However, developers working with the APEX_DATA_PARSER package can always create a cached temporary LOB themselves and pass that to APEX_DATA_PARSER.PARSE. For this use the DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY procedure with P_CACHE => TRUE to create the temporary LOB, then DBMS_LOB.COPY to copy the data from the uploaded BLOB to the temporary BLOB and then pass the temporary BLOB to APEX_DATA_PARSER.PARSE.

E.g.

```
create or replace function create_cached_blob( p_file in blob ) return blob 
is
    l_blob blob;
begin
    dbms_lob.createtemporary( lob_loc => l_blob, cache => true );
    dbms_lob.copy( 
        dest_lob => l_blob, 
        src_lob  => p_file, 
        amount   => dbms_lob.lobmaxsize);

    return l_blob;
end create_cached_blob;
```

then use this function in APEX_DATA_PARSER as follows:

```
:
apex_data_parser.parse(
     p_content                     => create_cached_blob( f.BLOB_CONTENT),
     p_max_rows                    => 3000,
:
```

Comment: This did solve the problem. Thank you very much!
Performance wise it performed as good as with files below 50MB. 
FYI my biggest file is 408MB with 1,6million rows and it takes ~30min. Hence End-users will get a gateway time-out error. But the process finishes just fine behind the scenes. So once the process completes the end-users can continue the process...(In another page which looks at the data parsed/loaded to a interface table)
Only change I did to the code was to add a if, so files are only changed if their size exceed 50MB.

Answer (score 0):

To improve the performance of APEX_DATA_PARSER.parse it would be helpful to pre-compute the profile of a file (which could be quite time consuming).

The function returns the file profile in JSON format.

```
select apex_data_parser.discover(
           p_content => {BLOB containing XLSX file},
           p_file_name=>'large.xlsx' ) as profile_json
from dual;
```

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.2/aeapi/DISCOVER-Function.html#GUID-D0DC85D9-A731-4EC0-A1F1-E662B30C6894

This profile can then be used in the parse function (so the parse function don't have to do this additional step of getting file information):

```
select * 
from A41_temp_files  f,
    table(  
            apex_data_parser.parse(
                p_content                     => f.BLOB_CONTENT,
                p_max_rows                    => 3000,
                P_DETECT_DATA_TYPES => 'N',
                p_file_name                   => f.FILENAME,
                p_file_profile => {File profile JSON}
            ) 
        ) p
where 1=1
and f.filename = 'CHUCK_47mb.txt' --3000 lines    1,9sec
--and f.filename = 'CHUCK_54mb.txt' --3000 lines 88,6sec
order by col001
;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't make any difference.
FYI, the calculated json_profile was the same for both files. (as it should be).
Actually it took a few seconds longer to run the script when adding the JSON profile upfront, but again it can of course be caused by caching/other running jobs etc.
Anyway bottom line is that it didn't resolve the issue.