# Problem uploading large excel files to apex_data_parser

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I wrote code that uses apex_data_parser to import data from an Excel file to the database.
Everything is fine until I upload a small file. But when I upload an Excel file with a size of 43 MG, both the uploading time is long and the part of entering the data into the database is very long and finally it gives an error.(A meaningless error like: no data found in uploaded file)
How can I solve this problem?
I also used the content of this link:

[Oracle APEX apex_data_parser execution time explodes for big files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60616754/oracle-apex-apex-data-parser-execution-time-explodes-for-big-files)

but it had no effect.

An example of my code for the insert in the table:

```
Insert into E5ASSET
 (CODE,NAME,PERSIANTITLE,UNITPRICE,ISACTIVE,ISPRODUCTION,ISTOOLS,T5TOOLS_ID,SERIALNUMBER,COP,EQPTYPE,E5PARENT_ID,R5DEPT_ID,E5CLASS_ID,E5TYPE_ID,E5CATEGORY_ID,E5PROFILE_ID,
 E5HC_CRITICALITY_ID,E5HC_SHUTDOWNTYPE_ID,M5MFC_ID,E5EQUIPMENTSTATUS_ID,EQUIPMENTVALUE,MODEL,REVISION,E5HC_CURRENCY_ID,E5HC_UOM_ID,COMMISSIONDATE)
 
 Select col003 CODE,col004 NAME,col005 PERSIANTITLE,col006 UNITPRICE,col007 ISACTIVE,col008 ISPRODUCTION,col009 ISTOOLS,q1.id T5TOOLS_ID,col012 SERIALNUMBER,col013 COP,
 col014 EQPTYPE,q2.id E5PARENT_ID,q3.id R5DEPT_ID,q4.id E5CLASS_ID,q5.id E5TYPE_ID,q6.id E5CATEGORY_ID,q7.id E5PROFILE_ID,q8.id E5HC_CRITICALITY_ID,q9.id E5HC_SHUTDOWNTYPE_ID,
 q10.id M5MFC_ID,q11.id E5EQUIPMENTSTATUS_ID,col035 EQUIPMENTVALUE,col036 MODEL,col037 REVISION,q12.id E5HC_CURRENCY_ID,q13.id E5HC_UOM_ID,col042 COMMISSIONDATE 
 
 from apex_application_temp_files f,
                     table ( apex_data_parser.parse (  
                            p_content=> f.blob_content,
                            p_skip_rows=>207833,
                            p_max_rows=>207834,
                            p_file_name=> f.filename)) p
                            left join T5TOOLS q1 on  q1.code=p.col011 and  q1.r5Organization_id=12377745557146463808
                            left join E5EQUIPMENT q2 on  nvl(q2.code,'*')=p.col016 and  q2.r5Organization_id=12377745557146463808
                            left join R5DEPT q3 on  q3.code=p.col018 and  q3.r5Organization_id=12377745557146463808
                            left join E5CLASS q4 on  q4.code=p.col020 and  q4.r5Organization_id=12377745557146463808
                            left join E5TYPE q5 on  q5.code=p.col022 and  q5.r5Organization_id=12377745557146463808
                            left join E5CATEGORY q6 on  q6.code=p.col024 and  q6.r5Organization_id=12377745557146463808
                            left join E5PROFILE q7 on  q7.code=p.col026 and  q7.r5Organization_id=12377745557146463808 
                            left join E5HC q8 on  q8.code=p.col028 and  q8.hc_id=6 and  q8.r5Organization_id=12377745557146463808
                            left join E5HC q9 on  q9.code=p.col030 and  q9.hc_id=7 and  q9.r5Organization_id=12377745557146463808
                            left join M5MFC q10 on  q10.code=p.col032 and  q10.r5Organization_id=12377745557146463808
                            left join E5EQUIPMENTSTATUS q11 on  q11.code=p.col034 and  q11.r5Organization_id=12377745557146463808
                            left join E5HC q12 on  q12.code=p.col039 and  q12.hc_id=1 and  q12.r5Organization_id=12377745557146463808
                            left join E5HC q13 on  q13.code=p.col041 and  q13.hc_id=7 and  q13.r5Organization_id=12377745557146463808
```

I do a line by line insert to access the line number for when an error occurred

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your tables; **YOUR** code that you are using for the upload; a **minimal** example of an excel file that replicates the problem; and the expected output for that minimal example. If you cannot tell us how to replicate the problem then how are we expected to provide you with an answer unless we randomly guess?

Comment: That link points nowhere for me... what version of apex are you on ?

Comment: @KoenLostrie The link is fixed. We are using apex 20.1

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the documentation of the PARSE function:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/23.1/aeapi/PARSE-Function.html#GUID-B815CF74-C469-4F78-9433-643D1339E930

> If the BLOB passed to APEX_DATA_PARSER.PARSE is less than 50 MB, Oracle APEX copies the BLOB to an internal, cached temporary LOB. Thus all CSV parsing is done in memory. For larger BLOBs, APEX does CSV parsing on the original BLOB locator. If it is selected from a table, CSV parsing can happen on disk but might be significantly slower. Note that a perfo
> rmance degradation may occur when parsed CSV files grow beyond 50 MB.
> However, developers can also use the DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY (passing CACHE => TRUE ) and DBMS_LOB.COPY procedures in order to explicitly create a cached temporary LOB, even for a larger file. Instead of the original BLOB, the cached temporary LOB can be passed to APEX_DATA_PARSER.PARSE. This approach also enables in-memory parsing for files larger than 50 MB.